# "[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" with python socket to Docker

Tags: python, docker

I am running a Docker container on Windows which is basically made from Ubuntu Image with some add-ons(asterisk pbx). When I try to connect to it(I take IPv4 from ipconfig's "WSL") with python socket:

```
import socket

a = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
a.connect(('172.19.96.1', 5038))
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\project\test.py", line 43, in <module>
    a.connect(('172.19.96.1', 5038))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

How do I connect to it? I am 100% sure my container is listening to 0.0.0.0:5038 as I can connect to it from inside of the container.

btw I tried to change '172.19.96.1' to '127.0.0.1' and 'localhost' both, but all the same I'm getting that error.

Comment: that message said you has firewall on destination

Comment: I have disabled ufw inside ubuntu container